# Docusign - How do I skip Obtaining Consent

Tags: docusignapi

I searched through previous questions but I haven't found a clear answer. My work flow is as follows:

- I have  a front end web app that talks to a node back end.
- The node backend create a PDF and we would like for the user to sign it.
- We use Authorization Code Grant
- The user is redirected to the Obtain Consent screen
- Once consent is granted they are redirected back to our app with a code that is swapped for an access token
- We then use that access token to create our envelope and redirect our user to docusign for signing.

I would like to REMOVE the NEED for the user to provide consent. I have seen other companies leverage docusign without needing it.

My questions are:
-  Is Authorization Code Grant the right authentication approach or should I be using JWT Grant?
- How can I get an access token for the user without obtaining consent? This seems like a necessary step?
- If I switch to the "Organizational Admin" approach, does my work flow change where I no longer re-direct the user to obtain consent? IF this is the case, how do I get an access token?

The users who are signing the document are not part of our company and do not share the same 'company email domain'.

I'd really welcome all feedback on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you just need users to sign, they do not need to log in to DocuSign at all. They don't even need to have a DocuSign account to sign.
2. Consent is only needed once per user/app. It cannot be avoided, as the user must agree to the app doing things for them.
3. If you use JWT - there's no need to login except once.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for taking the time. 

All I need is for the user to just sign, but they are redirected to the document to sign VIA my app. How can I make it so I get an access token to create the envelope without them needing to log in to do the signing? Does "Organizational Admin" tie into this at all or is it unrelated?

Comment: you can use JWT, and use your own account as the only account that you use to make API calls. You can generate a URL for them to sign the envelope using your account, but they are the signers.

Comment: PERFECT- that should work. I had thought I needed to create a JWT for every single signer. I will follow your advice and only create one JWT and re-use that for every single signer. THANKS SO MUCH!

Comment: In This case, I would need to keep refreshing the JWT every 8 hours using a CRON probably. Are there any drawbacks of following this process?

Comment: the only drawback is that all calls are done in the context of the same user. But that works for many people.